# MobX, and connection between stores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, mobx, mobx-react

guys.
I`m working on ract+mobx+firebase app.
I want to separate my app logic to 3 stores:

- **authStore** - store, where all firebase auth actions is happens
- **userStore** - where, stored all current user data, that came from firebase database
- **edtorStore** - all, stuff that happens in the editor component.

So to receive currentUser data from db , I firstly need to get the **currentUser.uid** from **fb.auth()**.
My **AuthStore** look like this:

```
class AuthStore {
    @observable auth = {
        authUser  : null,
        authError : null
    };

    constructor () {
        console.log ( 'start auth' );
        this.unwatchAuth = Fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged ( user => {
            console.log ( 'status changed' );
            this.auth.authUser = user;
        } );
    }

    @computed
    get currentUser () {
        console.log ( 'updated' );
        return this.auth.authUser;
    }
}

const authStore = new AuthStore ();
export { authStore };
```

My **UserStore**:

```
class CurrentUser {
    @observable user = ( {} );
    constructor () {
            this.userRef       = Fb.dbRoot.ref ( `users/${user.uid}` );
            this.userRef.on ( 'value', ( snapshot ) => {
                this.user = snapshot.val ();
            } );
        } );
    }
}

const user = new CurrentUser ();
export { user };
```

All my stores I import to one global store

```
import { authStore } from './AuthStore';
import { user } from './CurrentUser'
import { editor } from './EditorStore'

const store = {
    authStore,
    user,
    editor
};

window.store = store;

export { store };
```

And then import this store where they need.

Now I have some questions:

1. How I can set my `userStore.user` in `userStore` constructor, if I need
   receive `currentUser.uid` from authStore? 
   I`ve tried to import **authStore** to **userStore** and versa, but it didn`t help, because both watchers (**authStatusChange** and **userRef.on(‘value’)** must be placed at the store constructor (am I right?). 
   And because I create an instance of **storeClass** at the beginning – they instantiated before `auth.currentUser` get positive response from server.  I solve this issue, by inserting **authStatusChange** watcher in both stores, but I think it’s not good solution
2. In my app some components can be displayed only when **userStore.user** exist, and if I not make **user @observable** – I can check by `if(user)…`, 
   but because his observable `if(user)` return true – because his return observable object. How I can check if user already settedUp or not?
3. User in db have field – **project**. Project is the deeply nested object, that I use to describe the user project structure and display on the front. 
   When user enter to the Editor – editor component split this project to the blocks.
   Every block have his style property, that user can edit.
   So when user select some block, this block is writted in the **editorStore** as **currentBlock** observable object, by using **@action setCurrentBlock**, and as argument receive the reference to the selected block.

   class EditorStore {
       @observable currentBlock       = null;

   ```
   constructor () {
   }

   @computed
   get blockStyles () {
       return this.currentBlock.style
   }

   @action
   setCurrentBlock ( block ) {
       this.currentBlock = block
   }

   @action
   updateBlockStyle ( data ) {
       const { styleProp, value }           = data;
       this.currentBlock.style[ styleProp ] = value;
   }
   ```

   }

   const editor = new EditorStore ();
   export { editor };

So my **editStylesPanel** component is displaying the current block styles value that came from **@computed blockStyles**. 
Everything is fine, but when I change some style property through **@action updateBlockStyle** – his update only the styles of **editorStore.currentBlock**, and does not change the style in the relevant block of **user.project**. 
I was sure that if I send a reference to the object –as any changes in t editorStore must be happens on the root object.
Why is this not happen?

4. And the last questions – what is the better way to inject stores to the components? 
   Through `<Provider store={…stores}>` and `@inject(‘store’)` 
   Or by `import {store} from ‘./store/store’`

Thanks for you help ;)

Comment: 1. I would propose not to make the AuthStore singleton in the AuthStore module itself. This will allow you to pass userStore to AuthStore constructor;
2. Implement @computed method in the userStore. This method should check id property of the user object. Use this computed method in observable components that depend on the user  object.

Comment: 4. Use injection - this improves testability of your code and allows to mock store easily without the need to change component;

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in the very same situation:

```
// src/stores/index.js

import {RouterStore} from 'mobx-router5';
import AuthStore from './AuthStore';

const stores = {};

const routerStore = new RouterStore(stores); // Provide access to other stores
const authStore = new AuthStore(stores);

stores.routerStore = routerStore;
stores.authStore = authStore;

export default stores;


// src/stores/AuthStore.js

export default class AuthStore {
    ...
    constructor(stores) {this.stores = stores}; // Keep stores reference for later
    ...
}
```

Though it works, I hope there's a better solution. Maybe [this one](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree).

Comment: And this is exactly what @Evgeny Sorokin says about

Answer (score 0):

you can save a reference of your stores in the [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object

```
export const storesLoader = () => {
  const stores = {
    routerStore: new RouterStore(),
    authStore = new AuthStore()
  };

  if (global && typeof global.stores != 'object') {
    global.stores = stores;
  }
}
```

then access the stores by the global object itself.

- but remember, if you want to change an observable of a store in another store, define an action for it. otherwise, your new value is not going to trigger the Mobx observers.